# Apple ID Conflict With iCloud Locked iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I recently decided to restore my iPhone to the latest iOS 7.1.1 and got stumped by a serious problem. It’s an iPhone 5 and when I got it, I had it linked with an Apple ID/email that I no longer have access to.

I decided to change the account linked with the Find My iPhone app on my iPhone to an email/account I now have access to. On attempting to restore my iPhone, I get a message that my iPhone was setup with the previous account and I need that account's Apple ID and password to activate my iPhone. The Apple ID is masked but I can still remember some string of text of the Apple ID email, but not the password. I have no idea what to do, I have searched and searched for a way to contact Apple by mail all to no avail.

The iPhone is mine and already has Find my iPhone linked to the new account but was first activated with the old Apple ID. I'll really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to contact Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact support in three possible ways:

- by [phone](http://support.apple.com/kb/he57)
- by [chat](https://getsupport.apple.com/Issues.action)
- or you can even try this [online support request](https://ssl.apple.com/asia/support/itunes/contact.html)

Comment: But isn't that link to the online support request supposed to be for iPhone support and not iTunes?